# Drive Letter to Device Instance ID

Tags: windows, device, hardware-interface, device-instance-id

How do I get from a drive letter to a device instance ID?

My process starts with a device arrival message. I have been successful in getting the drive letter from the arrival message and in opening the dvd tray.

I have searched the various Setup API items; but I haven't found anything that gets me from a drive letter to a device instance ID.

A solution in C# or VB.NET would be ideal, but I'm willing to figure it out from any other language as long as I can see the API calls.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6):

You cannot do it directly.

The link is to use `STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER`.  You can use DeviceIoControl with `IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER` on your device name to populate this structure.  Put this value to one side.
You then need to get device infomation on your system using `SetupDiGetClassDevs` setting the GUIDS as approriate, indicicating the drives your are insterested in.  Then enumerate through the devices using `SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo`.  Then enumerate the interfaces using `SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces` and finally get the information using `SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail`.  In this structure returned you can get a DevicePath you can use to get the `STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER` as above.  Match this with the `STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER` from your drive letter, and you have now linked a driver letter to your structure.  Phew!  Inside this structure is a DevInst.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's years later but I had to do this and searching brought me here and @DanDan 's answer worked.  In order to save future people a lot of work, I thought I'd give back a little and present the technique a bit more explicitly.  You'll still have to write a bit of code, but the part I found difficult is below as code:

As DanDan mentioned, the idea is to use `CreateFile` and `DeviceIoControl` to get the Windows `STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER` for the disk associated with a file path, and then use the Setup  API to enumerate disk devices until we find one whose device instance equals the SDN.

First, here's a summary of how you get the `STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER` from the path (e.g. `c:\\users\\bob`);

1. Strip the path to the root (e.g down to `C:`) and prepend it  with `\\\\.\\`  so you have `\\\\.\\C:`
2. Open that path up using `CreateFileW` with to get metadata
3. Use `DeviceIoControl` with `IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS` to get the extents
4. Get the `DiskNumber` member from the first extent returned.
5. Close the file
6. Open up `\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive<n>` where `<n>` is the that DiskNumber from the first extent
7. Use `DeviceIoControl` with code `IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER` to get make it fill out a `STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER` struct as output
8. Use `SetupDiGetClassDevs` with arguments `&GUID_DEVCLASS_DISKDRIVE` and `DICGF_PRESENT` to get all disks on the system
9. In a loop, use `SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo` to get a `SP_DEVINFO_DATA` repeatedly (on the device list returned by step #8 above) and a call the function below to determine which one, if any, matches the `STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER` for the give path.

(This is edited to remove custom utility classes of mine right on the SO web page so I might have introduced errors/typos)

```
bool DoesDeviceInstanceEqualStorageDeviceNumber(
    const std::string&      devInstance, 
    STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER   sdn)
{   
    // Open up this device instance, specifying that we want the *interfaces*.
    // The interfaces are key key because examining them will let us get a 
    // string we can use the Win32 CreateFile function.  

    const auto hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevsA(
        nullptr,
        devInstance.c_str(), 
        nullptr, 
        DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE | DIGCF_ALLCLASSES);

    if (hDevInfo == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        throws std::runtime_error("Unable to get disk devices");


    DWORD dwSize = 0;
    SP_DEVINFO_DATA did;
    WCHAR buffer[4096];

    did.cbSize = sizeof (did);
    bool foundValidMatch = false;
    int deviceNumber = 0;

    // Iterate through all such devices, looking for one that has a storage device number that matches the given one.

    while ( !foundValidMatch &&  SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDevInfo, deviceNumber, &did))
    {
        deviceNumber++;

        DEVPROPTYPE devPropType;

        // We'll only bother comparing this one if it is fixed.  Determine that.

        const auto getPropResult = SetupDiGetDevicePropertyW (
            hDevInfo, 
            &did, 
            &DEVPKEY_Device_RemovalPolicy,  // Ask for the "removal policy"
            &devPropType, 
            (BYTE*)buffer, 
            sizeof(buffer), 
            &dwSize, 
            0);

        if (!getPropResult)
        {
            std::cerr << "Unable to to get removal policy for disk device: " << ::GetLastError() << std::endl;
            continue;
        }

        /*  This bit *would* skip removable disks, you wanted...
        else if (buffer[0] != 1)
        {
  
            std::cerr << "Skipping removable disk device " << devInstance << std::endl;
            continue;
        }
        */

        // OK this is a fixed disk so it might be the one we'll compare against
        // 1. Get the very first disk interface from this particular disk device
        // 2. Open a file on it
        // 3. Query the resulting file for its device number.
        // 4. Compare the device number to the one we determined above
        // 5. If it matches ours, then we succeed.  If not, continue

        SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA devIntData;
        devIntData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA);

        // Get the disk interfaces
        const auto result = SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(
            hDevInfo,
            &did, //&did,
            &GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK, // Get Disk Device Interface (from winioctl.h)
            0,                       // We only need the very FIRST one.  I think...
            &devIntData);

        if (!result)
            continue;

        DWORD dwRequiredSize = 0;

        // Want to get the detail but don't yet know how much space we'll need
        // Do a dummy call to find out

        SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(
            hDevInfo, 
            &devIntData, 
            nullptr, 
            0, 
            &dwRequiredSize, 
            nullptr);

        if (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER != ::GetLastError())
        {
            std::cerr << "Unable to get device interface Detail: " << ::GetLastError() << std::endl;;
        }
        else
        {

            // Get the detail data so we can get the device path and open a file.

            std::vector<TCHAR> buf(dwRequiredSize);
            auto pDidd = reinterpret_cast<PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA>(buf.data());

            // WARNING: HARD CODED HACK
            // ------------------------
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405193/vb-net-hid-setupdigetdeviceinterfacedetail-getlasterror-shows-1784-error-inv
            //
            // Don't ask.  Just do what they tell you. 
            // -----------------------------------------------------------------
#ifdef BUILD_64
            pDidd->cbSize = 8;
#else
            pDidd->cbSize = 6;
#endif
            // -----------------------------------------------------------------

            if (!SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(
                hDevInfo, 
                &devIntData, 
                pDidd, 
                dwRequiredSize, 
                &dwRequiredSize, 
                nullptr))
            {
                std::cerr << "Cannot get interface detail: " << ::GetLastError());
            }
            else
            {
                // FINALLY:  We now have a DevicePath that we can use to open up
                // in a Win32 CreateFile() call.   That will let us get the
                // STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER and compare it to the one we were given.

                const auto hFile = ::CreateFileW(pDidd->DevicePath, 0, FILE_SHARE_READ, nullptr, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
                if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hFile)
                {
                    std::cerr << "Unable to open logical volume: " + devicePath << std::endl;
                    continue;
                }
 
                STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER sdnTest;
                ZeroMemory(&sdnTest, sizeof(STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER));


                if (0 == DeviceIoControl(
                     hDevInfo
                     IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER,
                     nullptr,            // output only so not needed
                     0,                  // output only so not needed
                     &sdnTest,
                     sizeof(STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER),
                     nullptr, 
                     nullptr))
                {
                    std::cerr << "Unable to determine storage device number: " << ::GetLastError() << std::endl;);
                }
                else
                {
                    // All this for a one-line test...

                    foundValidMatch = sdnTest.DeviceNumber == sdn.DeviceNumber; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hDevInfo);
    return foundValidMatch;
}
```

I hope this saves someone a headache

Answer (score 1):

i know it's late for you now but not for everybody ^^

I had the same need and this is main line of how I did it:

-You need a window to receive device arrival and removal (as you said)

-Then you create a DeviceNotificationFilter initiated to dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE

-Then in the message loop of your window you look for VM_DEVICECHANGE

-When u receive it if wParam == DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL, use the lParam to check if it is a DBT_DEVTYPE_VOLUME (i was getting the letter and the type of the drive here) or a DBT_DEVTYPE_DEVICEINTERFACE ( there you can use your wellcasted lParam to get the InstanceId from the input structure).

When you connect a drive your receive DEVINTERFACE first then the other.
I only give the main line beacause i did this long time ago and i don't have the code here, and also I had found a lot of code pieces on the net (long time ago so there should be more now ^^^) maybe msdn give a full code example to do that now.

If you read this and need more informations, i'll reply or make a full documented answer if many need it.

Hope it will help some of you.