# c#.NET USB device persistent identifier

Tags: c#, .net, usb, persistence, uniqueidentifier

I am looking for a way in C# to have a persistent (across when end-users unplug a hub/restart their computer) identifier for USB slots, more specifically, SD card readers. Drive letters are not always assigned to the same slot, but I need a way to identify Slot A physically; as once I can identify it, I can make the connections to a drive letter.

So my question(s):

1. Is this possible?
2. If so, how would I go about getting these identifiers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WMI class Win32_USBHub.

```
ManagementObjectSearcher sidQuery = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * From Win32_USBHub");
ManagementObjectCollection results = sidQuery.Get();
List<String> deviceID = new List<String>();
foreach (ManagementObject result in results)
{
   deviceID.Add(result["DeviceID"]);
}
```

See more here : [Get List of connected USB Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331043/get-list-of-connected-usb-devices)

Documentation about Win32_USBHub : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394506(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks! One more question, is there a way to find out if Windows has assigned the USB device any letters (assuming the device is a drive and not a keyboard for instance) and if so, what they are/it is?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the solution to the comment question. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467506/how-to-have-the-drive-letter-with-the-device-id-on-windows7)